# Make jQuery getScript() know other variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

```
var some_array = [
    1, 2, 3, 4
];
$.getScript('{% static 'js/input_field_validations.js' %}');
```

My function inside `input_field_validations.js` says:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: some_array is not defined
```

`input_field_validations` is executed before I need it or what is happening here? since `static`-loading is from django, I added the tag

Comment: Is `some_array` globally available? Try `window.some_array = []`

Comment: @AlfonsoGarnett good point, i will test now

Comment: Or just leave out the `var` to make it global.

Comment: `'use strict';` wouldn't like that.

Comment: @DanielRoseman this did it. but now ``{% url "myurl" %}`` inside included js not being rendered by django, since it is not processed anymore, right?